# Continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ whose fibers are infinite

Tags: functions

Show that there exists a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that  $\forall y\in[0,1]$, all the [fibers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28mathematics%29) $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ have infinite cardinality.

Comment: I did not understand your question...

Comment: Oh!! Ok thanks, i will do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a continuous surjective path $\phi : [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ and project $\pi$ to one argument to get $f = \pi \circ \phi$. Then each fiber of $f$ is the preimage of an uncountable line segment. See [Space-Filling Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curves).

Answer (score 9):

The Peano-curve (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) is a uniformly continuous space filling curve $\phi:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$. Compose it with a projection $\pi$ of the first coordinate. Projections are continuous and the composition of continuous functions is continuous, so $\pi \circ \phi$ is continuous. But for every $y \in [0,1]$ there were uncountably many $x \in[0,1]$ with $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$ so $\pi\circ \phi$ will have uncountable fibers for every $y \in [0,1]$.

Edit: To clarify on @JasonDeVito's comment.

Certainly not every space filling curve has this property. For instance, the projection of  a space filling curve that fills the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ might not have infinite fibers at $x=\pm 1$.

The reason the fibers must be infinite in this case is because for any given $x$, there are infinitely many $y$ such that $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$. Just for concreteness, take $x=0$. Then $(0,1),(0,1/2),(0,1/3),\ldots,(0,1/n)$ are all elements of $[0,1]^2$. Since the Peano curve fills the square, this gives distinct $t_1,t_2,t_3\ldots \in [0,1]$ with $\phi(t_i) = (0,1/i)$. But the projection $\pi$ doesn't look at the second components, it only sees the first, so $(\pi \circ \phi)(t_i) = 0$ for all $i$. This gives infinitely many elements in the fiber of $x=0$. The exact same argument can be used for all $x \in [0,1]$ and it may be slightly modified to show that all the fibers are uncountable, not just infinite.

Comment: To make sure I'm undestanding, is it a fact that *every* space filling curve, when projected, has uncountable fibers?  Or is it just the special example Peano found?

Comment: @JasonDeVito See my edit.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how the plot of such a function would look like.

Comment: @nullUser:  Thanks for that, I was just being *extremely* dense.

Comment: @Marco probably something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:WeierstrassFunction.svg not to scale obviously.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=0.d_1d_2\ldots d_n\ldots$ is the decimal expansion of $x$, define $f(x)=0.d_2d_4\ldots d_{2n}\ldots$ Clearly f is continuous and every fiber has infinite (actually continuum) cardinality.

Sorry for the writing. I'm not momentarily familiar with LaTex.

Comment: Check out http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: So, sending $0.d_1d_2\ldots$ to $(0.d_1d_3\ldots, 0.d_2d_4\ldots)$ and $1$ to $(1, 1)$ defines a continuous surjection $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]^2$? I never expected to see such an elementary example of a space-filling curve. Wait, no... isn't that map injective?

Comment: @myself: no it isn't, for example $0.1$ and $0.0090909\ldots$ are both sent to $(0.1, 0)$.